# Изменение автора программы в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Всем привет. В ходе разработки своих первых приложений столкнулся с неприятностью. VS где-то записывает имя автора программы "devel", хотя мой ник - "developman2013". Также заметил, что это win10 режет длинные имена пользователей, и в C:/users/ также стоит "devel". Видимо, VS берёт имя пользователя где-то оттуда. Пробовал добавлять нового пользователя с полным длинным ником - там всё в порядке. Но не хотелось бы постоянно переключаться на другой профиль для работы. В общем, задача состоит в том, чтобы в VS изменить имя разработчика на "developman2013", дабы больше не пришлось переключать пользователя. Жду ваших ответов, заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А у вас в винде имя пользователя случаем не devel?

Comment: Увы, в самой винде почти везде вылазит полный ник, сокращённый замеил лишь в C:/Users/ и в самой Visual Studio.